# CPLEX Optimization shows no errors but doesn´t run the optimization part

Tags: performance, optimization, cplex

I implemented an MIP optimization in CPLEX.
When I run the model, CPLEX does not show any errors and executes everything properly.
But it stops on its own within the minimization part after seconds without solution.
The solution for all my decision variables says: "No Value".

What could that mean?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

this could mean your model is not feasible.

If you name your constraints, you could get some relaxation and conflicts.

Within [Simple OPL CPLEX](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-decision-optimization-simple-alex-fleischer/) see [Conflicts and relaxations](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooconflictandrelaxation.mod)

[image: Conflicts and relaxations]

Comment: I named my constraints. Suddenly it shows values for my decision variables. There is also a value for my objective. Is that on coincidence? The conflict window shows two conflicts. The relaxation window shows a few relaxations. The statistic window shows "no solution (infeasible)". So what do the values of decision varibles and my objective mean, if the solution is infeasible?

Comment: Yes your model is infeasible and what you go is a relaxed solution